New Services Added in MauiProgram.cs Are Not Being Instantiated in .NET Blazor Hybrid MAUI Project
I’m working on a .NET Blazor Hybrid MAUI project, and I’m trying to set up a local SQLite database using SQLite-PCL. However, I've run into an issue where any new service I add to MauiProgram.cs doesn't seem to be registered properly. Specifically, when I set a breakpoint in the constructor of my BitacoraContext class, which is responsible for initializing the database, the breakpoint is never hit.
Here’s what I’ve done and what I’ve observed:

I have other services already added in MauiProgram.cs, and they are working fine.

When I added the BitacoraContext service, I noticed that the constructor was never reached. I tried removing references to SQLite in the constructor, but the problem persisted.

I then duplicated another working service, renamed it, and added it to MauiProgram.cs. Surprisingly, the constructor for this duplicated service was also never reached.

I even tried creating a service with just a constructor that does nothing, added it to MauiProgram.cs, but still, the constructor wasn’t hit.


At this point, it seems that any new service I add to MauiProgram.cs is not being instantiated at all. I’ve tried the following to resolve the issue:

Reordered the service registrations in MauiProgram.cs.

Deleted the bin and obj folders.

Cleaned the solution and rebuilt it multiple times.


Unfortunately, none of these steps have resolved the issue.
// MauiProgram.cs
using BitacoraMovil.DAL;
using BitacoraMovil.Utils;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Reflection;

namespace BitacoraMovil
{
    public static class MauiProgram
    {
        public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
        {
            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder
                .UseMauiApp<App>()
                .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                {
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                });

            builder.Services.AddMauiBlazorWebView();

            var a = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
#if DEBUG
            using var stream = a.GetManifestResourceStream("BitacoraMovil.appsettings.json");
#else
            using var stream = a.GetManifestResourceStream("BitacoraMovil.appsettings.Development.json");
#endif

            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonStream(stream)
            .Build();

            builder.Configuration.AddConfiguration(config);

            builder.Services.AddScoped<CallServicesUI>();

            builder.Services.AddScoped<SyncService>();
            builder.Services.AddScoped(p=> new BitacoraContext(ConexionDB.DevolverRuta("bitacora.db")));

            builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<CustomAuthenticationStateProvider>();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider>(s => s.GetRequiredService<CustomAuthenticationStateProvider>());

#if DEBUG
            builder.Services.AddBlazorWebViewDeveloperTools();
            builder.Logging.AddDebug();
#endif

            var app = builder.Build();

            return app;
        }
    }
}

// BitacoraContext.cs
using SQLite;

namespace BitacoraMovil.DAL
{
    public class BitacoraContext
    {
        public readonly SQLiteConnection db;
        public BitacoraContext(string path)
        {   

            var db = new SQLiteConnection(path);
            db.CreateTable<Sucursal>();
            db.CreateTable<Seccion>();
            db.CreateTable<SeccionTab>();
            db.CreateTable<TabArea>();
            db.CreateTable<AreaTarea>();
            db.CreateTable<Supervision>();
            db.CreateTable<SupervisionDetalle>();
            db.CreateTable<SupervisionDetalleFoto>();

            this.db = db;
        }
    }
}


May I know what's the version of SQLite-PCL you are using and what platform you are testing it?

sqlite-net-pcl version 1.9.172 | I am testing on windows machine

I can reproduce the issue that the breakpoint was never hitting constructor of BitacoraContext when running the app.
To fix it(initialize the db), you can create the MyBitacoraContext.cs like below:
public class MyBitacoraContext
{
        private readonly SQLiteConnection db;

        public MyBitacoraContext(string dbName)
        {
            var dbPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), dbName);

            db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath);

          //db.CreateTable<Sucursal>();
        }
}

And then add it in MauiProgram.cs:
builder.Services.AddSingleton(new MyBitacoraContext("bitacora.db"));

For more details, you can refer to .NET MAUI local databases.

I already do that in the ConexionDB.DevolverRuta method, which is located in MauiProgram.cs.

You may need create a MyBitacoraContext.cs(see my answer) because using ConexionDB.DevolverRuta won't reach the breakpoint.

I already tried that. I was saying that whenever I create any other new service (even a copy of another one that already works with just the name changed), it doesn't work.

@FernanOwO  I think it's related with the way you registered service with AddScoped as this will new() again every time it receives a request while the program is running.  You may need register the service with AddSingleton<T> see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/maui/dependency-injection#registration
